# Bootstrap dropdown menu doesn't work in my rails application during development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a rails (3.2) application using bootstrap. This application includes a dropdown menu that insists in not working when I run the app in development mode. The funny thing is that it worked before.

This is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue might happen if the assets are precompiled during development. During development the unminifed files for bootstrap are included and the resource containing the minified version of all the javascripts (/assets/application.js?body=1) should be empty. If the assets are precompiled (rake assets:precompile) applications.js will be generated and code duplication will occur.

Cleaning the precompiled assets should fix the issue (rake assets:clean)